# How to Translate text coming from server in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am facing translation problems in Flutter. I am using internationalization features in my app to give additional language options to users. I managed to translate app texts but failed with the texts coming from the server. When users choose the language they can add their profession (the List of the professions) for ex. in Italian which is saved in the server and when another user chooses the English language they shouldn't be able to search in English to find this user. How I can achieve to translate texts coming from the server or is there any option to choose a different path? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it mandatory to translate the text on the user's device or you can translate it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter internationalization can not translate dynamic words which are coming from anywhere else, except the words you translated yourself manually. Google Translate uses machine learning to translate one word to another. You can the Google Translate API to translate the word before adding it to the server database and save both words on your server database. Then display the word based on whichever `Locale` is selected by the user.